# ADFS Powershell script to add additional SamlEndpoints to existing

Tags: powershell, adfs

This question likely doesn't require actual knowledge of ADFS, but I'm providing that for context. The command "Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -Name X -SamlEndpoint Y" overwrites all SAML endpoints with what you specify. What I'd like to do is create a script that takes the existing SAML endpoints and sets them as variables so that I can then add them all back along with the new endpoint.

If there's only one existing endpoint, I can put it into a variable using this and it works:

```
$EP = New-AdfsSamlEndpoint -Binding "POST" -Protocol "SAMLAssertionConsumer" -Uri "https://test.com" -Index 1
$EP1 = Get-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -Name "X" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamlEndpoints 
Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName "PsTest" -SamlEndpoint $EP,$EP1
```

The problem with this is that, if multiple endpoints exist, expand-property returns them all as a single value which breaks the function. Using "-limit 1" doesn't work because the whole output of expand-property is considered 1.

What I can do is to generate a numbered list of each index value using this command:

```
Get-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -Name "X" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamlEndpoints | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Index
```

and then create a unique variable for each corresponding index value

```
$EP1 = Get-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -Name "X" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamlEndpoints | Where-Object {$_.Index -eq 2}
```

But in order to completely script this rather than setting variables by hand, I'd need automate setting "$_.Index -eq" to each index value that's output from "-ExpandProperty Index", and to assign a unique variable to each of those, which is where I'm stuck. What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: Returns them all as a single value _of what type_? Can you add an example to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to these command so I am having to guess a little here, but it looks like your command

```
Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName "PsTest" -SamlEndpoint $EP,$EP1
```

accepts an array for the -samlEndpoint parameter.

What I would do it work with the arrays like so.

```
$EP = New-AdfsSamlEndpoint -Binding "POST" -Protocol "SAMLAssertionConsumer" -Uri "https://test.com" -Index 1
$EndPoints = @(Get-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -Name "X" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamlEndpoints)

$Endpoints += $EP
Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName "PsTest" -SamlEndpoint $EndPoints
```

Comment: Unfortunately the output of "$EndPoints = @(Get-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -Name "pstest" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamlEndpoints)" is spit out as one single response including all endpoints. $EndPoints winds up including everything, and it looks like $EP contains nothing. Running that command results in error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: It may look like 1 long item, but it should be an array. Check the value of $Endpoints.count to confirm... And if $EP is nothing you need to double check the code you posted, it is a straight copy/paste from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Take the following code as an example. This code reads the input of the first three variables and then creates new endpoints based on the input.

In this example, we prepare the new endpoints in variable `$NewSamlEndpoints`. For each URL that you define, we add a new SAML endpoint, i.e. a POST binding or Artifact binding. Analogous for the logout URLs. Simply comment out or modify the endpoint types that you do not need.

```
$NewACSEndpoints = 'https://...', 'https://...'
$NewLogoutEndpoints = 'https://...', 'https://...'
$RelyingPartyName = 'My App'

$RelyingParty = Get-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -Name $RelyingPartyName
$SamlEndpoints = $RelyingParty.SamlEndpoints
$HighestIndex = ($SamlEndpoints.Index | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
$NewSamlEndpoints = $SamlEndpoints

foreach ($ACSEndpoint in $NewACSEndpoints) {
    $HighestIndex++
    $NewSamlEndpoints += (New-AdfsSamlEndpoint -Binding POST -Protocol SAMLAssertionConsumer -Uri $ACSEndpoint -Index $HighestIndex -IsDefault $false)

    $HighestIndex++
    $NewSamlEndpoints += (New-AdfsSamlEndpoint -Binding Artifact -Protocol SAMLAssertionConsumer -Uri $ACSEndpoint -Index $HighestIndex -IsDefault $false)
}


foreach ($LogoutEndpoint in $NewLogoutEndpoints) {
    $NewSamlEndpoints += (New-AdfsSamlEndpoint -Binding POST -Protocol SAMLLogout -Uri $LogoutEndpoint)
    $NewSamlEndpoints += (New-AdfsSamlEndpoint -Binding Redirect -Protocol SAMLLogout -Uri $LogoutEndpoint)
}

Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName $RelyingPartyName -SamlEndpoint $NewSamlEndpoints
```